# MIMEBase: conversion to bytes and back again removes \r in binary data: Documented or just broken behavior in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mime-message

It seems to me like email.Message.as_bytes is broken:

```
import email

from email.encoders import encode_7or8bit
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

orig_data = b"Zeilenenden\n<Unix\r\n<DOS\rMac"

msg = MIMEBase('application/octet-stream', "gzip")

msg.set_payload(orig_data)

encode_7or8bit(msg)

print("orig_data = %r" % orig_data)
print("payload   = %r" % msg.get_payload(decode=1))

b = msg.as_bytes()
msg2 = email.message_from_bytes(b)
print("payload2  = %r" % msg2.get_payload(decode=1))
```

The output is

```
orig_data = b'Zeilenenden\n<Unix\r\n<DOS\rMac'
payload   = b'Zeilenenden\n<Unix\r\n<DOS\rMac'
payload2  = b'Zeilenenden\n<Unix\n<DOS\nMac'
```

Note how the conversion message > bytes > message breaks the binary payload.

This used to work with similar code in Python 2.

Is this a bug or intended and if so where is it documented?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my use case is more or less invali???

Obviously, Python 3 uses base64 encoding for binary data and does not support transferring pure bytes.

Anyway, by looking into the source code of the email package, I came up with the following workaround:

```
import io
import email
import email.generator

from email.encoders import encode_7or8bit
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

orig_data = b"Zeilenenden\n<Unix\r\n<DOS\rMac"

msg = MIMEBase('application/octet-stream', "gzip")

msg.set_payload(orig_data)

encode_7or8bit(msg)

print("orig_data = %r" % orig_data)
print("payload   = %r" % msg.get_payload(decode=1))

class MyBytesGenerator(email.generator.BytesGenerator):
    def _write_lines(self, lines):
        self.write(lines)

def as_bytes(msg, unixfrom=False, policy=None):
    """Return the entire formatted message as a bytes object.

    Optional 'unixfrom', when true, means include the Unix From_ envelope
    header.  'policy' is passed to the BytesGenerator instance used to
    serialize the message; if not specified the policy associated with
    the message instance is used.
    """
    from email.generator import BytesGenerator
    policy = msg.policy if policy is None else policy
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    g = MyBytesGenerator(fp, mangle_from_=False, policy=policy)
    g.flatten(msg, unixfrom=unixfrom)
    return fp.getvalue()

b = as_bytes(msg)
msg2 = email.message_from_bytes(b)
print("payload2 = %r" % msg2.get_payload(decode=1))
```

With this workaround, the as_bytes function and email.message_from_bytes allow transferring the message in binary format without base64-overhead.